# Component unit test: By.css() does not match when in SVG namespace

Tags: svg, angular

In short, I'm looking for a way to make the predicate `By.css([css-selector])` (see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/By-class.html) work in Angular2 (v2.0.1+) component unit tests when a namespace (SVG) is involved.

(The related predicates `By.all()` and `By.directive(DirectiveClass)` work fine.)

Below is a self-contained spec to demonstrate the issue.  The result is

```
DivComponent class specs:
    ✔ NG should evaluate component and template.
    ✔ Div should be locatable by tag.
    ✔ Div should be locatable by id.
    ✔ Div should be locatable by class.
    ✔ Match should fail a negative.
ShapesComponent class specs:
    ✔ NG should evaluate the component and template.
    ✖ Circle should be locatable by tag.
    ✖ Circle should be locatable by ns:tag.
    ✖ Circle should be locatable by id.
    ✖ Circle should be locatable by class.
```

Spec:

```
import {TestBed, ComponentFixture} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {Component, DebugElement} from '@angular/core';
import {By} from '@angular/platform-browser';

/*
 * A simple component in HTML namespace
 */
@Component({
    selector: '[app-div]',
    template: '<div class="myDivClass" id="myDivId">Hello World</div>'
})
export class DivComponent {
}

/*
 * A simple component in SVG namespace
 */
@Component({
    selector: '[app-shape]',
    template: '<svg:circle class="myCircleClass" id="myCircleId" ' +
    'cx="80" cy="80" r="20"></svg:circle>'
})
export class ShapesComponent {
}

function dumpElements(elements: DebugElement[]) {
    console.log('Matcher found ' + elements.length + ' elements.');
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        console.log('element[' + i + '] = '
            + elements[i].nativeElement.tagName
            + ': ' + elements[i].nativeElement.outerHTML);
    }
}

/* 
 * Test "By.css()" on the DivComponent.
 */
describe('DivComponent class specs:', () => {

    let divComponent: DivComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DivComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                DivComponent
            ]
        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DivComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        de = fixture.debugElement;
    });

    it('NG should evaluate component and template.', () => {
        // Dump elements if needed:
        // dumpElements(de.queryAll(By.all()));
        expect(de.queryAll(By.all()).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Div should be locatable by tag.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('div')).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Div should be locatable by id.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#myDivId')).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Div should be locatable by class.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('.myDivClass')).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Match should fail a negative.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#negative')).length).toBe(0);
    });
});

/* 
 * Use the same "By.css()" syntax on the ShapeComponent.
 */
describe('ShapesComponent class specs:', () => {

    let divComponent: ShapesComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShapesComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                ShapesComponent
            ]
        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShapesComponent);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        de = fixture.debugElement;
    });

    it('NG should evaluate the component and template.', () => {
        // Dump elements if needed:
        // dumpElements(de.queryAll(By.all()));
        expect(de.queryAll(By.all()).length).toBe(1); // pass
    });

    it('Circle should be locatable by tag.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('circle')).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Circle should be locatable by ns:tag.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('svg:circle')).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Circle should be locatable by id.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('#myCircleId')).length).toBe(1);
    });
    it('Circle should be locatable by class.', () => {
        expect(de.queryAll(By.css('.myCircleClass')).length).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: Got it to work by doing a querySelector on the nativeElement instead: `element.nativeElement.querySelector('.chart')`

Comment: @herkulano post it as answer instead..

Comment: @JGFMK thanks! didn't check the notifications, sorry for the very long delay :(

Comment: **Update:** I have confirmed that `By.css()` now works with SVG elements in Angular 5 (starting with v5.0.0).  It is still broken in Angular 4 (tested up to v4.4.6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it to work by doing a querySelector on the nativeElement instead:

```
element.nativeElement.querySelector('.chart')
```

Comment: Yes, seems this is the best approach for Angular 4 and earlier.   (In Angular 5, `By.css()` is fixed and can be used with SVG elements.)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I'm having this problem in Angular 5 too.  It doesn't work if I do this:

```
debugElement.query(By.css('svg.underline'))
```

However, if I do this, it works just fine:

```
debugElement.query(By.css('svg[class=underline]'))
```

Answer (score 0):

@herkulano posted in comments:

> Got it to work by doing a querySelector on the nativeElement instead: element.nativeElement.querySelector('.chart')

Comment: Wasn't sure what to do as the user who posted the answer didn't seem to be coming back so followed advice [in this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat)